# Xcode: Make a image accelerate then button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am looking for some help with my Xcode project.

I would like to make an image move to a specific position then button is clicked. But it has to accelerate and not just move (disappear from start position and appear on end location). So it has to animate.

Hope you can help me out!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: before acceleration btn's userenteraction will be false but when animationDidFInished then btn's userenteraction will be true.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve an animation to a new position with the `UIView` animation block. Example below..

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender {

           UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

           [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{

           [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,button.frame.size.width,button.frame.size.height)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }]

}
```

This above method will take your button and move it to position `{100,100`} on it's superview with a duration of `1` second, and with an animation curve of `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear`. You can see your options for animation curves in the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) documentation.